# Named parameters vs regular ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is some difference in performance between javascript's regular parameters

```
call(var1, var2);
```

and jQuery style:

```
call({var1: '1', var2: '2'});
```

I am using the both depenging on current situation.

Maybe there is some standard?

Thank you

Comment: You mean for such methods like `css()` or `attr()` where you may pass a map as an argument?

Comment: I know what you mean, but note that what you are calling "regular parameters" _are_ named parameters assuming the function declaration is like `function call(var1, var2)`. (But you can call a JS function passing more arguments than formally declared and still access the "leftovers" within the function via the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), and these extra arguments won't have names.)

Comment: @BastiM sorry, couldn't find this question

Comment: @BastiM - That's not a duplicate. The other question isn't about function arguments, which matters when talking about performance and other reasons for using one way over the other.

Comment: @nnnnnn you're right, i'm sorry for this.

Comment: @nKognito You have a fundamental misunderstanding of javascript objects and parameters. Passing a `{ param: value }` is not 'jQuery style' you are simply passing an object to your method as one "regular" parameter. You could replace either parameter in the first method example with a `{ param: value }` if you wanted. As for performance, perhaps there is some extra work to construct that object, but likely negligible for all practical purposes (unless you are doing some crazy recursion or looping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, It all depends on what your scenario is. If you have `var1, var2, ... varN` you would obviously either use array or JSON. I do not think there is any issue with the performance.

If I have only one parameter in my function, Why would i want to use json (creation of json might use some resource).

Comment: _"If you have `var1, var2, ... varN` you would obviously either use array or JSON."_ - not necessarily, you might use the `arguments` object within the function. Also, there's no JSON here, just an object literal.

Comment: So actually it's all about json object creation time?

Answer (score 2):

That's not *jQuery style*, but just a Javascript Object Literal actually.

You choose literals when you have to pass a map of named values, but you don't know which ones and how many will be passed actually, e.g. jQuery CSS setter:

```
$(el).css({
  'color' : 'red',
  'font-weight' : 'bold'
});
```

The function body will take care of inspecting the argument object, and do stuff accordingly

You choose a plain list of arguments [`function(arg1, arg2, ... argN)`] when you possibly know all the parameters needed by the function, and you are able to provide them:

```
var distance = function(p1, p2){

  // calculate distance between points p1 and p2

}
```